# Angularjs:-Slick not working for dynamic data in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel

I am trying to implement a slick carousel in which we can display images of various friends.

The issue I am facing is that when I am working on slick on desktop it is working fine, but as soon as I move into mobile mode/mobile screen the slick carousel breaks. I am not sure whether it is the problem with the image width or size for that matter

The below is the image of what issue I am facing:

[image]

As you can see the images are coming one below the other instead of a default carousel.

I am making an API call to fetch the data and display the result. This is my HTML file:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4" style="border: 1px solid;height: 400px;">
  <slick settings="jumboSlickPanel" style="position: inherit !important;">
    <img class="thumbnail_fan" ng-repeat="fanbook in fan" src="{{'https://files.bewakoof.com/uploads/fanbook/thumbs/'+fanbook.image.image_file_name}}" style="line-height: 0px;">
  </slick>
</div>
```

I have used the below code to stop the element getting overflowed. But now the images are not loading by default. If I change the width of the screen it then seems to work perfectly fine. I have added the following:

```
<slick class="slick_conf" settings="jumboSlickPanel" ng-if="dataLoaded" data="dataLoaded" init-onload="false" style="position: inherit !important;">
  <img class="thumbnail_fan" ng-repeat="fanbook in fan" src="{{'https://files.bewakoof.com/uploads/fanbook/thumbs/'+fanbook.image.image_file_name}}" style="line-height: 0px;width: 96%;">
</slick>
```

Can someone please help me out and tell me how to trigger the carousel?

Thanks for the help.